# Storing resized images in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I've been wondering on how to resize image and store it into database.

So far, I could store the image into database. Now, I want to create the the thumbnail of relevant image and store it in differently with my actual image.

Let's say, from an image.jpg, I want to store the actual image into file_data (LONGBLOB) and its thumbnail into thumbnail_data (BLOB).

But, I don't know how to resize the image. I've tried several tutorials but nothing works for me.

Please help? Sorry for troubling you guys.

=======================(newly added part)

I was thinking to store the image into database because I need the relation within the data stored in each row.

I have this in my database table

**image_id** | identifier | filename | mime_type | file_size | file_data | thumbnail_data

Identifier is used to classify the images when they get uploaded.

Let's say I have this:

1 | newyork | ny1 | ...
2 | newyork | ny3 | ...
3 | newyork | ny2 | ...
1 | taiwan  | tw1 | ...

the images will be displayed as:

New York:

ny1.jpg ny3.jpg
ny2.jpg

Taiwan:

tw.jpg

Comment: Why do you store images in DB? There is a filesystem for files.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay?lq=1 for why storing images in the db is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Emm... you do *not* want to store binary data in a database. What you (and everyone else) should do is store the files on the filesystem and put pointers to the files in the database.

```
image_id | identifier | file_location         | mime_type | file_size | thumbnail_location
1        | foo        | /images/hd1/first.png | image/png | 10240     | /images/thumbnails/hd1/first.png
```